# How are airdrops sent to token holders when NFTs do not belong to contracts?

Tags: nft, token

Since NFTs on Cardano do not belong to a contract, how can token holders be rewarded with an airdrop? Do they need to request it themselves by showing proof of ownership?

Answer (score 1):

Having the NFT on an UTxO on your address is the proof of ownership.
How the token holders receive an airdrop (automatically or only after claiming it) only depends on how the one doing the airdrop wants to do it.

Comment: I should have formulated my question better: is there a way for those airdropping to know the owners of the tokens? I do not see how this could work on Cardano. In Ethereum each NFT-owner would be known through the contract

Comment: By owner you mean the person holding the NFT?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Is there a record of who owns what?

Comment: No, the persons owning the wallets are not known. Is there any blockchain where that is public information?

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do. All NFTs are named [poliyID].[TokenName]. Simply put that into cardanoscan.io and you can see the wallet that holds any particular NFT. You then just mint (airdrop) a new token into that wallet. Done.

Take for example this blockowl:

3f4360edd7f689b637b44587150e71453a51ba29655336ff374c201c.BlockOwlsStake001

If you put the above into CardanoScan and click Top Holders, you will find the wallet it lives in:

addr1q87xqs5duasp4ehuec9gasy9qptt7zhweg046gh9pa7nmax6yxvvxd5qhurea4rvlj6a8c35twc0654l48avkn79z3mq46yfdm